# Deserializing XML in C# when there a collection/list and single element

Tags: xml, xml-parsing

I am having a XML as below:

```
<FreightResponse>
    <Rate>
        <Carrier>C1</Carrier>
        <Service>S1</Service>
        <PublishedRate>P1</PublishedRate>
        <DiscountedRate>D1</DiscountedRate>
        <EstmatedTime>E1</EstmatedTime>
    </Rate>
    <Rate>
    <Carrier>C2</Carrier>
        <Service>S2</Service>
        <PublishedRate>P2</PublishedRate>
        <DiscountedRate>D2</DiscountedRate>
        <EstmatedTime>E2</EstmatedTime>
    </Rate>
    <ERROR_RESPONSE>ABF Error response will be appear here
    </ERROR_RESPONSE>
</FreightResponse>
```

Now I am able to get the Rate details by using

```
List<Rate> rateList = (List<Rate>)serializer.Deserialize(stringReader);
```

but don't know how to get the `ERROR_RESPONSE` value using the serializer, I am able to get by using

```
var errorMessage = rootElement.Element("ERROR_RESPONSE").Value;
```

but I want to know **how to get it using serializer**

Answer (score 0):

If you are using "XmlSerializer" then below code would work.

```
public class Rate {
    public string Carrier { get; set; }
    public string Service { get; set; }
    public string PublishedRate { get; set; }
    public string DiscountedRate { get; set; }
    public string EstmatedTime { get; set; }
}
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRoot("FreightResponse")]
public class FreightResponse {
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement("Rate")]
    public List<Rate> Rate { get; set; }
    public string ERROR_RESPONSE { get; set; }
}
FreightResponse rateList = (FreightResponse)serializer.Deserialize(stringReader);
```

You have list of "Rate" object inside "FreightResponse" class object.

Comment: Yes...That i am getting i want to get the "ERROR_RESPONSE " element by using the XmlSerializer